# How to change binding object?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm create a application using binding for popularize `TextBlock` Text
This is my Grid

```
<Grid Name="ClientGird">
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
</Grid>
```

In the code behind I had instance a Client object and set it to `this.DataContext`

```
MainWindow : Window
{
    public Client client { get; set; }
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = client;
    }
}
```

When I change value of `client` `Name` attribute, it will show in the Window

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = client;
    client.Name = "John";
}
```

So, but when I try change object for `client`, window no show new context, why does this happen?

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = client;
    client = myOtherClientObject;
}
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: In addition to the answers below, it doesns't appear that you're actually initializing `client`, or it's not shown

Comment: it not show 'myOtherClientObject' Name, but myOtherClientObject is not null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to do it this way:

```
this.DataContext = myOtherClientObject;
```

Your code `client = myOtherClientObject;` do not change what the `DataContext` is referencing, it's still referencing the "old" `client` value.

Here is a little [reminder](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3ewxz6et%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) of how reference types are working in C# (from msdn) :

> Variables that are value types store data, and those that are
>   reference types store references to the actual data. Reference types
>   are also referred to as objects.

Your `client` variable is a reference type, so `client` is only referencing data (it is not data) and `DataContext` is referencing the same (thanks to `DataContext = client;`). When you change the data your `client` variable is referencing (with `client = myOtherClientObject;`), it doesn't affect `DataContext` and the data it is referencing.

Comment: It is work, but is impossible solve this changed 'client' object only?

Comment: Binding is get context direct from your DataContext reference object?

Comment: Do you want to change your client variable (only) because your are using it elsewhere in the same class?

Comment: Yes, and I also want to know if it is possible.

Comment: Then you should create a new property (able to notify the view see INotifyPropertyChanged interface or DependencyProperty) into your MainWindow class called Client. You would use this property to assign the current client. To bind it, you would set DataContext = this; and bind you textblock to Client.Name.

Comment: Thank you! I think what can I do now

Answer (score 1):

Do your Client class implements

> [INotifyPropertyChanged](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.aspx)

interface. This will notify your view when something changes in ViewModel or ViceVersa.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing to this concept:

```
 this.DataContext = client;
 this.DataContext = null;
 this.DataContext = myOtherClientObject;
```